# When is one exempt from giving rebuke?

Tags: halacha, rebuke-tochacha

It says that one should rebuke his friend if he sees he's doing something wrong and if he doesn't it's counted as if he did wrong what that person was doing . Are there any exceptions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

on one hand
[Leviticus.19.17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920#v=17&showrashi=true)

> You shall not hate your brother in your heart. **You shall surely rebuke your fellow**, but you shall not bear a sin on his account.

rashi

> **but You shall not bear a sin on his account:** (means) I.e., [in the course of your rebuking your fellow,] do not embarrass him in public. — [Torath Kohanim 19:43; Arachin 16b]

on the other hand
[Proverbs.9.8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16380#v=8&showrashi=true)

**Reprove not a scorner lest he hate you**; reprove a wise man and he will love you.

talmud on this subject

[yebamoth_65b](http://halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_65.html)

> R. Ile'a further stated in the name of R. Eleazar son of R. Simeon: As one is commanded to say that which will be obeyed, so is one commanded not to say that which will not be obeyed.

[Beitzah 30a](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Beitzah.pdf#page=97)

> But let Israel [go their way]: it is better that they should err in ignorance than presumptuously;

some exceptions in practical law are below,

and my summarizations in english of the text that i made bold

[Shulchan aruch harav 156.7,8](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/12/156/index.htm)

> הרואה את חבירו שחטא או שהלך בדרך לא טובה מצוה עליו להחזירו למוטב ולהודיעו שהוא חוטא על נפשו במעשיו הרעים שנאמר הוכח תוכיח את עמיתך ואם לא קיבל ממנו יחזור ויוכיחנו שנאמר הוכח תוכיח אפילו מאה פעמים **עד שיכנו החוטא או יקללנו ואינו מחויב להוכיח אלא עמיתו שהוא חבירו שהוא גס בו אבל איש אחר שאם יוכיחנו ישנאנו וינקום ממנו אינו צריך להוכיחו כיון שבודאי לא ישמע לו** אבל חבירו אפילו אם יודע שלא ישמע לו חייב להוכיחו אלא אם כן הוא חוטא בשוגג שאז אנו אומרים מוטב שיהיה שוגג ואל יהיה מזיד. **ורבים אפילו הם מזידין אין להוכיחם יותר מפעם אחת אם ידוע לו שדבריו אינם נשמעים ועל זה אמרו כשם שמצוה לומר דבר הנשמע כך מצוה שלא לומר דבר שלא נשמע ואם הם שוגגים אין להוכיחם כלל שמוטב שיהיו שוגגים ואל יהיו מזידים. במה דברים אמורים ביחיד המוכיח** אבל על **הבית דין מוטל להוכיחם** ולגעור בם שלא יהיו נתפשים באותו עון ואפילו הוא דבר שאיסורו אינו אלא מספק ואפילו אם רבים הם השוגגים ואין להם להשמט ולומר מוטב שיהיו שוגגין ואל יהיו מזידים **אלא אם כן הוא איסור שאינו מפורש בתורה ופרצו בו רבים מפני חסרון אמונתם באיסור שאז קשה מאוד למחות בידם שאי אפשר לבית דין להעמיד שוטרים בבית כל אחד ועל זה אמרו הנח להם לישראל מקצוף עליהם ומגער בם מוטב שיהיו שוגגין ואל יהיו מזידים:**

156.7

> even 100 times until the sinner hits him or curses him, he is only obligated to rebuke his "fellow"(as in the verse) that is his friend that he is close to **but anther person that if he will rebuke him will hate him and will take revenge from him he is does not need to rebuke him** since he knows that he will not receive from him
>
> and a lot (group) even if they are (sinning) on purpose, should not be rebuked more then once, and if he knows that his world are not being heard on this they said "just as it is a mitzva to say what will be heard so it is a mitzva not to say what will not be heard" if they (the lot) are (sinning) by mistake they should not be rebuked at all since it is "better that they be (sinning) by mistake then (sinning) on purpose" (since you know they will not listen to you) this was all by a single (person) that was rebuking but the bais din is responsible to rebuke them... unless it is a sine that is not written clearly in the torah and the masses broke (are sinning) it because of their lack in believe of this sin, so then it is very hard to protest, since it is impossible for the bais din to put gourds in everyone's house and about this they said "But let Israel [go their way]: it is better that they should err in ignorance than presumptuously;"

ח

> כל המוכיח את חבירו בין בדברים שבינו לבינו בין בדברים שבינו לבין המקום צריך להוכיחו בינו לבין עצמו וידבר לו בנחת ובלשון רכה ויודיעו שאינו אומר לו אלא לטובתו **ואם דיבר אתו קשות והכלימו עובר בלא תעשה שנאמר ולא תשא עליו חטא כך אמרו חכמים יכול אתה מוכיחו ופניו משתנות תלמוד לומר ולא תשא עליו חטא** (ואע"פ שרש"י שם פירש דהיינו כשיוכיחנו ברבים להלבין פניו הנה הסמ"ג והרמב"ם פירשו שלא יוכיחנו בדברים קשים עד שפניו נשתנות והיינו אפילו בינו לבינו) מכאן שאסור לאדם להכלים את חבירו אפילו בינו לבינו **ואין צריך לומר ברבים** לפיכך לא יקראנו בשם שהוא בוש ממנו ולא מספר לפניו דבר שהוא בוש ממנו וכל המלבין פני חבירו ברבים אין לו חלק לעולם הבא. **במה דברים אמורים בדברים שבין אדם לחבירו** **אבל בדברי שמים** אם לא חזר בו **צריך להוכיחו ברבים** עד שיחזור למוטב כמו שעשו כל הנביאים בישראל וכל זה בעבירה שבסתר אבל אם עבר עבירה בגלוי יוכיחנו מיד שלא יתחלל שם שמים **ותלמיד שראה את רבו עובר עבירה יאמר לו למדתני רבינו כך וכך להזכירו אולי שוגג הוא ואם אינו שומע לו לא יוכיחנו עוד מה שאין כן בחבירו כמו שנתבאר:**

8

> if he spoke-to (rebuked) him harshly he transgressed a negative commandment as it says "You shall not bear a sin on his account" the hachomim said "it (the posuk (You shall surely rebuke your fellow)) could have meant (that) you need to rebuke him so his face changes the (posuk (You shall not bear a sin on his account)) teaches us You shall not bear a sin on his account"
>
> obviously not in public
>
> this is talking about sins between man and man
>
> but between man and Hashem you need to ... in public
>
> a student that sees this master (teacher) sinning, (should) say to him my teacher you have taught me so and so, to remind him, maybe his is doing it by mistake, if he does not listen to him, he should not rebuke him again, not as by his (the rebuker's) friend as explained (above)

[608.4,5,6](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh4/3/608/index.htm)

ד

> נשים שאוכלות ושותות עד בין השמשות ממש והן אינן יודעות שמצוה להוסיף מחול על הקודש אין ממחין בידן אם הוא ידוע שבודאי לא ישמעו לנו ויעשו בזדון דמוטב שיהיו שוגגין ואל יהיו מזידין. וכן הדין בכל דבר איסור שאינו מפורש בתורה אלא שחכמים למדוהו ממדרש הפסוקים או שהוא קבלה בידם הלכה למשה מסיני או שהן בעצמן אסרו דבר ואדם אחד עובר על דבריהם בשגגה שאינו יודע האיסור ואף אם יודיע לו האיסור לא יקבל ממנו אינו צריך למחות בידו דמוטב שיהיה שוגג ולא יהיה מזיד:

ה

> **אבל דבר שאיסורו מפורש בתורה אע"פ שידוע לנו שהחוטא הזה לא יקבל ממנו אף אם נודיע לו האיסור אעפ"כ צריך למחות בידו לפי שכל ישראל ערבין זה בזה וע"י שמוחה בידו הוא מוציא את עצמו מהערבות. ומכל מקום לא יוכיחנו ברבים אלא פעם אחת אבל לא ירבה בתוכחות ברבים** מאחר שברור לו שלא יקבל ממנו ועל זה אמרו כשם שמצוה לאמר דבר הנשמע כך מצוה שלא לאמר דבר שאינו נשמע. אבל חייב להוכיחו ביחיד אפילו מאה פעמים עד שינזוף בו החוטא שכיון שהודיע לו האיסור והוא עובר עליו בזדון חייב כל אחד ואחד מישראל להוכיחו שנאמר הוכח תוכיח אפילו מאה פעמים. מכל מקום אם היא עבירה שבסתר יוכיחנו בתחלה בסתר ואם לא שב מדרכו מכלימים אותו ברבים עד שישוב אבל אם עובר עבירה בגלוי מוכיחין אותו מיד שלא יתחלל שם שמים:

5

> **but something that its forbiddeness is explicit in the torah, even though we know that this sinner will not except (the rebuke) from us, even if we inform him of the sin, still it is needed to protest since all Jews are arevim ze bo ze "Are responsible for each other" and through protesting he is taking himself out (separating himself) from the sin**, but sill he should not rebuke him **in public** more then once

ו

> **מי שהוכיח את חבירו ונזף בו חבירו החוטא לא יוכיחנו עוד על עבירה זו שנאמר אל תוכח לץ וגו':**

6

> someone that rebuked his friend and his friend the sinner reprimanded him, should not rebuke him again about this sin as it says "Reprove not a scorner..."

Comment: Is there an English translation of this?

Comment: @Sara i do not think online, but there is in print http://store.kehotonline.com/Shulchan-Oruch-English-Vol-4-Orach-Chaim-89-156/productinfo/EAR-SHULO4/ and http://store.kehotonline.com/Shulchan-Oruch-English-Hilchos-Rosh-Hashanah-Yom-Kippur/productinfo/EAR-SHULOHRHYK/ i am translating parts of it

Answer (score 1):

The Biur Halacha in siman 608:2: DH chayiv brings down the Magen Avraham seif 3 in the name of the Sefer Chassidim siman 413 that only  a pesron who one is close to(libo gas bo) he should rebuke,but another person one isnt obligated to rebuke him if he will be hated because of the rebuke.

In addition,The Chut Sheni Hilchos yom kippur 608:2 writes in the name of the Chazon Ish that if one will bring hatred because of rebuke then he is absolved of rebuking.